# HowTo: [Output File Cleanup] workaround for UNC targets

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016, maintenance, ola-hallengren

Hallengren job [Output File Cleanup] silently fails when the output file directory is a network file share.

Question:  Is there a better, cleaner way to resolve the issue detailed below when the job step Output File destination is a network file share.

---

UNC paths are not supported by the job [Output File Cleanup] when setting SET @OutputFileDirectory to a file share.  Sample error.

ERROR: UNC paths (\machine\share) are not supported.

---

Sample command:

cmd /c "For /F "tokens=1 delims=" %v In ('ForFiles /P "\MyBackupServer01\Backup$\SQLServerToBackup02\MaintenancePlanLogs" /m *_*_*_*.txt /d -30 2^>^&1') do if EXIST "\MyBackupServer01\Backup$\SQLServerToBackup02\MaintenancePlanLogs"\%v echo del "\MyBackupServer01\Backup$\SQLServerToBackup02\MaintenancePlanLogs"\%v& del "\MyBackupServer01\Backup$\SQLServerToBackup02\MaintenancePlanLogs"\%v"

Full text of sampled error as directly observed from CMD prompt:

c:\ >if EXIST "\MyBackupServer01\Backup$\SQLServerToBackup02\MaintenancePlanLogs"\ERROR: UNC paths (\machine\share) are not supported. echo del "\MyBackupServer01\Backup$\SQLServerToBackup02\MaintenancePlanLogs"\ERROR: UNC paths (\machine\share) are not supported.   & del "\MyBackupServer01\Backup$\SQLServerToBackup02\MaintenancePlanLogs"\ERROR: UNC paths (\machine\share) are not supported.

---

Workaround:

echo ""  && echo ""  && echo ""  && echo "" && echo Starting delete of files on: && date /t && time /t && echo \MyBackupServer01\Backup$\SQLServerToBackup02 && pushd \MyBackupServer01\Backup$\SQLServerToBackup02 && echo Search Criteria:  .\MaintenancePlanLogs /M *_*_*_*.txt /D -30  /C && echo. && ForFiles /S /P .\MaintenancePlanLogs /M *_*_*_*.txt /D -30 /C "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE echo @file && dir @file && echo DEL @file && DEL @file " & popd && echo ""  && echo Cleanup finished.

Comment: On a related note, the result of the message "ERROR: UNC paths (\machine\share) are not supported" is that a job that silently fails and no files are deleted on the output file share.

Comment: To confirm: the error is coming from the Ola Hallengren script itself, and is something it's checking for? Note that there are frequently permissions issue with SQL Server jobs and network file shares, if the user running the SQL Server Agent service doesn't have permissions on the file shares.

Comment: I had similar problems with unc paths (which do work btw) in my case i resolved it using a domain login for sql server and agent services and ensuring that user had full permissions on the file share.